# EF Code first Error with relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new with EF and I've some problem with a one-to-one Relationship.
I've the following message and i don't understand why :

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Order' does not declare a navigation property
>   with the name 'orderAdress'.

The code that i used is the following. Hope that someone can help me.

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    public OrderAdress Adress { get; set; }
    public int CustomerNo { get; set; }
}

public class OrderAdress
{
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders {get; set;}
    public DbSet<OrderAdress> OrderAdresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderAdressMap());

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasRequired(order => order.Adress)
            .WithRequiredDependent(orderAdress => orderAdress.Order);
    }
}

public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.OrderNo);
        Property(t => t.CustomerNo);
    }
}
public class OrderAdressMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderAdress>
{
    public OrderAdressMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.OrderNo);
        Property(t => t.country);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added relationships between two tables?

Comment: If someone answered your question, please accept the Answer. Put a Green Check mark on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because your Address table doesnt contain any primary key.try adding a primary key to ypur tale.

Comment: You're welcome, and Thank you too TFFR .. This is my first accepted answer.Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your missing the `Navigation Property` setup in your `EF design`.

For a very good overview of EF and Dealing with Navigation Properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Here's an example taken directly from that link I posted:

[image]

[image]

Make sure you have properly setup your relationship in your design, and check your Class and compare to the examples provided in the Link above.